# Extract different links from various Google Sheet cells, paste them in a Google Doc Template as Active URLs /Hyperlinked using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to achieve the following with Google Apps Script:

1. If a cell is a text, display the text in the placeholder (achieved with the below code)
2. If a cell is a URL, display it as an active URL or a hyperlinked URL - Currently, this code pulls the URL's as text strings too.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am still quite a beginner in this language. I know the referencing of the placeholders is probably not a very efficient way to pull this large number of cells but I also don't have enough knowledge to implement it more efficiently.

All the placeholders from "body.replaceText('{{StrengthOneFoundationalA}}', row[42]);" will either return the text links or blank

```
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const menu = ui.createMenu('AutoFill Docs');
  menu.addItem('Create New Docs', 'createNewGoogleDocs')
  menu.addToUi();
}

function createNewGoogleDocs() {

  const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('1Olth1o_dIRZm6dpiltAesm5Q0ZeEFFb__6K5nVp26dA');

  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1O_j7K3RM6kXBttIPyNxe9o6kzI8N5ORM')

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Data')
 
  const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  const urls = sheet.getDataRange().getRichTextValue().getLinkUrl();
  rows.forEach(function(row, index) {
    if (index === 0) return;
    if(row[0]) return


 const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`${row[1]} ${row[2]} | Beta` , destinationFolder);

  const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())
  const body = doc.getBody();

    body.replaceText('{{First Name}}', row[1]);
    body.replaceText('{{Last Name}}', row[2]);
    body.replaceText('{{Email}}', row[3]);
    body.replaceText('{{Result}}', row[4]);
    body.replaceText('{{Mark}}', row[5]);
    body.replaceText('{{TopStrengthOneResult}}', row[6]);
    body.replaceText('{{TopStrengthOneDifficultyLevel}}', row[7]);
    body.replaceText('{{TopStrengthTwoResult}}', row[8]);
    body.replaceText('{{TopStrengthTwoDifficultyLevel}}', row[9]);
    body.replaceText('{{TopStrengthThreeResult}}', row[10]);
    body.replaceText('{{TopStrengthThreeDifficultyLevel}}', row[11]);
    body.replaceText('{{TopStrengthFourResult}}', row[12]);
    body.replaceText('{{TopStrengthFourDifficultyLevel}}', row[13]);
    body.replaceText('{{TopStrengthFiveResult}}', row[14]);
    body.replaceText('{{TopStrengthFiveDifficultyLevel}}', row[15]);
    body.replaceText('{{TopStrengthSixResult}}', row[16]);
    body.replaceText('{{TopStrengthSixDifficultyLevel}}', row[17]);
    body.replaceText('{{TopCategoryStrengthOne}}', row[18]);
    body.replaceText('{{TopCategoryStrengthTwo}}', row[19]);
    body.replaceText('{{TopCategoryStrengthThree}}', row[20]);
    body.replaceText('{{TopCategoryStrengthFour}}', row[21]);
    body.replaceText('{{TopCategoryStrengthFive}}', row[22]);
    body.replaceText('{{TopCategoryStrengthSix}}', row[23]);
    body.replaceText('{{TopWeaknessOneDifficultyLevel}}', row[24]);
    body.replaceText('{{TopWeaknessOneResult}}', row[25]);
    body.replaceText('{{TopWeaknessTwoDifficultyLevel}}', row[26]);
    body.replaceText('{{TopWeaknessTwoResult}}', row[27]);
    body.replaceText('{{TopWeaknessThreeDifficultyLevel}}', row[28]);
    body.replaceText('{{TopWeaknessThreeResult}}', row[29]);
    body.replaceText('{{TopWeaknessFourDifficultyLevel}}', row[30]);
    body.replaceText('{{TopWeaknessFourResult}}', row[31]);
    body.replaceText('{{TopWeaknessFiveDifficultyLevel}}', row[32]);
    body.replaceText('{{TopWeaknessFiveResult}}', row[33]);
    body.replaceText('{{TopWeaknessSixDifficultyLevel}}', row[34]);
    body.replaceText('{{TopWeaknessSixResult}}', row[35]);
    body.replaceText('{{TopCategoryWeaknessOne}}', row[36]);
    body.replaceText('{{TopCategoryWeaknessTwo}}', row[37]);
    body.replaceText('{{TopCategoryWeaknessThree}}', row[38]);
    body.replaceText('{{TopCategoryWeaknessFour}}', row[39]);
    body.replaceText('{{TopCategoryWeaknessFive}}', row[40]);
    body.replaceText('{{TopCategoryWeaknessSix}}', row[41]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthOneFoundationalA}}', row[42]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthOneFoundationalB}}', row[43]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthOneFoundationalC}}', row[44]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthOneIntermediateA}}', row[45]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthOneIntermediateB}}', row[46]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthOneIntermediateC}}', row[47]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthOneAdvancedA}}', row[48]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthOneAdvancedB}}', row[49]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthOneAdvancedC}}', row[50]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthTwoFoundationalA}}', row[51]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthTwoFoundationalB}}', row[52]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthTwoFoundationalC}}', row[53]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthTwoIntermediateA}}', row[54]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthTwoIntermediateB}}', row[55]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthTwoIntermediateC}}', row[56]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthTwoAdvancedA}}', row[57]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthTwoAdvancedB}}', row[58]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthTwoAdvancedC}}', row[59]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthThreeFoundationalA}}', row[60]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthThreeFoundationalB}}', row[61]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthThreeFoundationalC}}', row[62]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthThreeIntermediateA}}', row[63]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthThreeIntermediateB}}', row[64]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthThreeIntermediateC}}', row[65]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthThreeAdvancedA}}', row[66]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthThreeAdvancedB}}', row[67]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthThreeAdvancedC}}', row[68]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthFourFoundationalA}}', row[69]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthFourFoundationalB}}', row[70]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthFourFoundationalC}}', row[71]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthFourIntermediateA}}', row[72]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthFourIntermediateB}}', row[73]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthFourIntermediateC}}', row[74]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthFourAdvancedA}}', row[75]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthFourAdvancedB}}', row[76]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthFourAdvancedC}}', row[77]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthFiveFoundationalA}}', row[78]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthFiveFoundationalB}}', row[79]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthFiveFoundationalC}}', row[80]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthFiveIntermediateA}}', row[81]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthFiveIntermediateB}}', row[82]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthFiveIntermediateC}}', row[83]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthFiveAdvancedA}}', row[84]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthFiveAdvancedB}}', row[85]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthFiveAdvancedC}}', row[86]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthSixFoundationalA}}', row[87]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthSixFoundationalB}}', row[88]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthSixFoundationalC}}', row[89]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthSixIntermediateA}}', row[90]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthSixIntermediateB}}', row[91]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthSixIntermediateC}}', row[92]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthSixAdvancedA}}', row[93]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthSixAdvancedB}}', row[94]);
    body.replaceText('{{StrengthSixAdvancedC}}', row[95]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessOneFoundationalA}}', row[96]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessOneFoundationalB}}', row[97]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessOneFoundationalC}}', row[98]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessOneIntermediateA}}', row[99]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessOneIntermediateB}}', row[100]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessOneIntermediateC}}', row[101]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessOneAdvancedA}}', row[102]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessOneAdvancedB}}', row[103]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessOneAdvancedC}}', row[104]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessTwoFoundationalA}}', row[105]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessTwoFoundationalB}}', row[106]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessTwoFoundationalC}}', row[107]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessTwoIntermediateA}}', row[108]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessTwoIntermediateB}}', row[109]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessTwoIntermediateC}}', row[110]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessTwoAdvancedA}}', row[111]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessTwoAdvancedB}}', row[112]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessTwoAdvancedC}}', row[113]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessThreeFoundationalA}}', row[114]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessThreeFoundationalB}}', row[115]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessThreeFoundationalC}}', row[116]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessThreeIntermediateA}}', row[117]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessThreeIntermediateB}}', row[118]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessThreeIntermediateC}}', row[119]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessThreeAdvancedA}}', row[120]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessThreeAdvancedB}}', row[121]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessThreeAdvancedC}}', row[122]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessFourFoundationalA}}', row[123]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessFourFoundationalB}}', row[124]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessFourFoundationalC}}', row[125]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessFourIntermediateA}}', row[126]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessFourIntermediateB}}', row[127]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessFourIntermediateC}}', row[128]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessFourAdvancedA}}', row[129]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessFourAdvancedB}}', row[130]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessFourAdvancedC}}', row[131]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessFiveFoundationalA}}', row[132]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessFiveFoundationalB}}', row[133]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessFiveFoundationalC}}', row[134]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessFiveIntermediateA}}', row[135]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessFiveIntermediateB}}', row[136]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessFiveIntermediateC}}', row[137]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessFiveAdvancedA}}', row[138]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessFiveAdvancedB}}', row[139]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessFiveAdvancedC}}', row[140]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessSixFoundationalA}}', row[141]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessSixFoundationalB}}', row[142]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessSixFoundationalC}}', row[143]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessSixIntermediateA}}', row[144]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessSixIntermediateB}}', row[145]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessSixIntermediateC}}', row[146]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessSixAdvancedA}}', row[147]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessSixAdvancedB}}', row[148]);
    body.replaceText('{{WeaknessSixAdvancedC}}', row[149]);
 

    
    doc.saveAndClose();
  
    const url = doc.getUrl();
   
    sheet.getRange(index + 1, 1).setValue(url)
    
  })
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you correctly. If you need to get links (http...) or texts from some range (from column for example) it can be done about this way:

```
const values =  range.getRichTextValues().flat()
  .map(x => x = x.getLinkUrl() || x.getText());
```

It tries to get URL and if there no URL it gets text, for every cell of the range.

If you have not just one column but a 2d array there should be additional steps of course. But the core algorighm is the same: get a rich text, try to get a url from it, if url == null, get a text.

It would be easier to figure out if you share example of your date.